# MySQL output pulled into Javascript array results in ugly mess

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

Beginner coder struggling with what I'm guessing is a fairly simple problem. I have a webpage with a dropdown menu showing options built off of a javascript array. The current set is a static list of options:

```
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

I'm trying to replace that static list with values pulled from a table I have set up in a MySQL database. I'm able to pull in the values, but am having issues with the output being formatted correctly on the webpage.

Here's my SQL (which seems to be working fine):

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'coins';


$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM uscoins";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$testarray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ // cycle through each record returned
  $testarray[] = "\"".$row['name']."\""; // get the username field and add to the array above with surrounding quotes
}

$name_string = implode(",", $testarray); // implode the array to "stick together" all the usernames with a comma inbetween each

$conn->close();
?>
```

I updated the javascript to pull in values from the SQL query:

```
var countries = [<?php echo json_encode($name_string); ?>];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

But instead of returning the array values in separate rows within the dropdown menu on the webpage, it returns them all as a single text string.

So instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nswAr.png)

it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hTRg.png)

Is there something else I need to do to put the SQL output in the correct format for the javascript to process it in the same way as the static list?

Comment: `var countries = [<?php echo $name_string; ?>];` - your data is already good to go

Comment: Haha wow, that was certainly easy - thanks for the help!